Debian 12 weird ipv6 breaks internet access
I've setup a fresh Debian 12 system today and I wanted to try a bit of IPv6 in my network.
So I setup an IPv6 ULA on my router and created a new Debian VM for testing.
The debian VM picks up the ULA address through SLAAC just fine but it also generates a weird and wrong looking IPv6 along side of it which is just the EUI64 interface ID without any of the network id bits set.
The output of ip address looks like this:
inet6 ::be24:11ff:fe59:4e73/64 scope global
   valid_lft 2591891sec preferred_lft 604691sec
inet6 fdf2:e2f0:3d5b:0:be24:11ff:fe59:4e73/64 scope global deprecated dynamic mngtmpaddr
   valid_lft 2591893sec preferred_lft 0sec
inet6 fdf2:e2f0:3d5b:1:be24:11ff:fe59:4e73/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr
   valid_lft 2591893sec preferred_lft 604693sec
inet6 fe80::be24:11ff:fe59:4e73/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Although the ULA address is generated just fine, this non-routable address (:be24:11ff:fe59:4e73/64) breaks my internet access as its used as the source IP of ping or curl for example.
Do any of you know why this address is generated and how I can get rid of it?
Thank you!
Edit 1:
Output of rdisk6
Soliciting ff02::2 (ff02::2) on eth0...

Hop limit                 :    undefined (      0x00)
Stateful address conf.    :          Yes
Stateful other conf.      :           No
Mobile home agent         :           No
Router preference         :       medium
Neighbor discovery proxy  :           No
Router lifetime           :         1800 (0x00000708) seconds
Reachable time            :  unspecified (0x00000000)
Retransmit time           :  unspecified (0x00000000)
 Source link-layer address: 78:9A:18:94:4A:B4
 Recursive DNS server     : fdf2:e2f0:3d5b:1:be24:11ff:fe59:4e73
 Recursive DNS server     : fdf2:e2f0:3d5b:1:be24:11ff:feb6:90f
  DNS servers lifetime    :         1800 (0x00000708) seconds
 Prefix                   : fdf2:e2f0:3d5b:1::/64
  On-link                 :          Yes
  Autonomous address conf.:          Yes
  Valid time              :      2592000 (0x00278d00) seconds
  Pref. time              :       604800 (0x00093a80) seconds
 Prefix                   : fdf2:e2f0:3d5b::/64
  On-link                 :          Yes
  Autonomous address conf.:          Yes
  Valid time              :      2592000 (0x00278d00) seconds
  Pref. time              :            0 (0x00000000) seconds
 from fe80::7a9a:18ff:fe94:4ab4

Router address setup:
[gateway] > /ipv6/address/print detail  
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic; G - global, L - link-local; S - slave; d - deprecated 
 1  G   address=fdf2:e2f0:3d5b:1::/64 from-pool=private-pool interface= VLAN010 actual-interface=VLAN010 eui-64=no advertise=yes no-dad=no 
 
[gateway] > /ipv6/nd/print 
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid; * - default 
 0  * interface=all ra-interval=3m20s-10m ra-delay=3s mtu=unspecified reachable-time=unspecified retransmit-interval=unspecified ra-lifetime=30m ra-preference=medium hop-limit=unspecified advertise-mac-address=yes advertise-dns=yes 
      managed-address-configuration=yes other-configuration=no dns=fdf2:e2f0:3d5b:1:be24:11ff:fe59:4e73,fdf2:e2f0:3d5b:1:be24:11ff:feb6:90f


Hello @BobGoddard, thank you for your comment. In my post I'm referring to the ::be24:11ff:fe59:4e73/64 scope global address which does not have a network prefix.

Could you show your SLAAC configuration from the router (radvd.conf etc), and also show what you are actually receiving through SLAAC, by installing ndisc6 and running rdisc6 <interface> in the VM?

@grawity I've added the rdisk6 output as well as my router config. My router is a mikrotik router, I've tried to include all relevant config items.

If you run rdisc6 -m <interface>, is that the only RA that shows up? Does the weird address re-appear after reboot? Does its valid_lft ever reset to max every ra-interval, or does it continue counting down? And, what network software do you have running on the VM – how many SLAAC clients are there? (the kernel itself, systemd-networkd, dhcpcd, NetworkManager can all be responsible for SLAAC)

@grawity Yes the address re-appears after a reboot and rdisc6 -m <interface> shows only one RA. The valid_lft was reset after the reboot and is also reset after every RA. At the moment there are only 2 SLAAC clients. The kernel itself should be responsible for the SLAAC, systemd-networkd is running on the machine but the SLAAC config is done via /etc/networking/interfaces and iface eth0 inet6 auto

Yeah, that smells like someone is announcing ::/64.

@SimonRichter thanks for the hint. After reading it I found the option to let rdisc6 wait for longer with rdisc6 -w 60000 and lo and behold, I got a ::/64 RA from my LTE modem that is connected to the same network. It appears that I've never noticed it because I didn't use IPv6 in the past at all and it was off in my hosts. Thanks for getting me on the right track!
